# JQuery : how to limit CLICK (make slides)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, slide

My problem is if I press the "button" in rapid succession very fast, Images overlap. and if I press the "button" in rapid succession very fast, I stopped pressing the button, but the Slides will continue to work.

For example, if I press the button 20 times quickly, the image will overlap and the slide will work 20 times, slower than the button pressed speed.
So I would like to prevent the click method from running while the slide is moving by clicking on the "button". What should I do?

```
$(function(){
    var max =  $("header > img").length -1;
    var sno = 0;
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        $( $("header > img")[sno] ).animate({
            left: "100%"
            },1000,function(){
            $(this).css({left: "-100%"});
        });
        sno++;
        if( sno > max ) sno = 0;
        $( $("header > img")[sno] ).animate({
            left: "0%"
        },1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please first read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Then _"Please answer fast and good"_ will not help you to get good answers, but normally will bring down-votes for your question. So, Please create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and then edit your question and add the link of your fiddle to your post so we can investigate the cause of your issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set disable to button when button clicked.

```
$(function(){
    var max =  $("header > img").length -1;
    var sno = 0;
    $("button").on("click",function(){
        var button = this;
        $(button).prop('disabled', true);
        $( $("header > img")[sno] ).animate({
            left: "100%"
            },1000,function(){
            $(this).css({left: "-100%"});
            $(button).prop('disabled', false);
        });
        sno++;
        if( sno > max ) sno = 0;
        $( $("header > img")[sno] ).animate({
            left: "0%"
        },1000,function(){
            $(button).prop('disabled', false);
        });
    });
}
```

And release it in complete callback function.